# Create a Mercurial bookmark from another bookmark

Tags: mercurial

Is it possible in Mercurial to create a bookmark from another bookmark? I am trying to do what I used to do with Git: create a branch from another branch.

Comment: A branch from another branch is basically a branch from a commit (the last commit) of that branch, so in that sense you would just create a bookmark for that commit in mercurial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create a new bookmark that points to the same commit as an existing one, simply do:

```
hg bookmark -r OLD NEW
```

or

```
hg book -r OLD NEW
```

where `OLD` is the name of the existing bookmark and `NEW` the one that you are creating (the full command name is `bookmark`, but can be abbreviated).

That said, you do not need to create a bookmark in order to branch in Mercural (See "Branch, anonymous" in `hg help glossary`). There is no such thing as a detached head in Mercurial (since branches are not needed to keep revisions alive); you can simply branch of an existing commit without giving that anonymous branch a name. A bookmark can be useful to keep track of the head of an anonymous branch, but you can also accomplish this through other means (e.g. `hg share`), and it may not be necessary for simple operations or if you are using a GUI.